# Why does email sent from my site end up in SPAM folders?

Tags: django, email

I am developing a course registration website in Django. New users must confirm their email address by clicking on a link emailed to them.

Unfortunately, this message is consistently ending up in people's spam folders. What steps can I take to prevent this from happening? Should I include an unsubscribe paragraph? Should I send less mass mail from my site (I occasionally send out a message to 500 emails.)?

Comment: Jeff Atwood has a post on this exact topic: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: See also [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/148577/why-are-emails-sent-from-my-applications-being-marked-as-spam) on [ServerFault.SE](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Hi David, specific implementation troubleshooting questions like this aren't on-topic here: the link Matthieu provided is probably the best information we have on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Avoid any string that looks like spam.

> Most Spam checking these days is Bayesian, which means that that your
>   message is checked using a fuzzy algorithm that tries to guess if
>   resembles known Spam or Ham (good) messages (mainly by checking the
>   frequency of common spam words and phrases).

- Send individual messages to each recipient instead of copies.

> It is better to send an individual message to each recipient, rather
>   than using multiple addresses in the BCC field because many spam
>   filters (and many ISP's) automatically flag multiple recipients as
>   spam.

- If possible send via your ISP's mail server rather than using a local SMTP Server.

> Messages sent from a mail server running on your computer may be
>   flagged as spam because some mail servers will try to contact the
>   source IP of the sending server (which will fail with a local IP
>   address).

- Try with smaller batches of e-mails.

> It would appear that some of the big mail hosts such as Hotmail will
>   recognize when an identical message is sent to a large number of
>   subscribers at one time so you should stagger the delivery of your
>   messages [...]  to send your messages in small batches.

- Minimize your use of attachments.
- Make sure the computer sending the email has a Reverse PTR record.

> What's a reverse PTR record? It's something your ISP has to configure
>   for you -- a way of verifying that the email you send from a
>   particular IP address actually belongs to the domain it is purportedly
>   from.

- Configure DomainKeys Identified Mail in your DNS and code.

> What's DomainKeys Identified Mail? With DKIM, you "sign" every email
>   you send with your private key, a key only you could possibly know.
>   And this can be verified by attempting to decrypt the email using the
>   public key stored in your public DNS records.

- Set up a SenderID record in your DNS.

> To be honest, SenderID is a bit of a "nice to have" compared to the
>   above two. But if you've gone this far, you might as well go the
>   distance. SenderID, while a little antiquated and kind of..
>   Microsoft/Hotmail centric.. doesn't take much additional effort.
>
> SenderID isn't complicated. It's another TXT DNS record at the root
>   of, say, example.com, which contains a specially formatted string
>   documenting all the allowed IP addresses that mail can be expected to
>   come from.

Sources and additional information:

- [XeQute](http://www.xequte.com/support/maillistking/spamissues.html)
- [Spamassassin FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders)
- [Jeff Atwood's post on the same subject](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)
- [Post on the same subject on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/148577/why-are-emails-sent-from-my-applications-being-marked-as-spam)